# How to get React Testing Library's userEvent to type into an input

Tags: typescript, testing, react-testing-library

I can successfully implement a test with React Testing Library's `fireEvent` method, but when I try equivalent tests with `userEvent` I can't get it to trigger anything. How can I fix this?

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-wilson-9t71m9?file=/src/__tests__/MyInput.test.tsx:0-626)

`/MyInput.tsx`

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function MyInput() {
  const [inputTextState, setInputTextState] = useState("");
  return (
    <div>
      <label>
        My Input
        <input
          value={inputTextState}
          onChange={(event) => setInputTextState(event.target.value)}
        />
      </label>
      <p>{inputTextState}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`__tests__/MyInput.test.tsx`

```
import { fireEvent, render } from "@testing-library/react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import MyInput from "../MyInput";

const setup = () => {
  const utils = render(<MyInput />);
  const input = utils.getByLabelText("My Input") as HTMLInputElement;
  return {
    input,
    ...utils
  };
};

test("Simply input a number with fireEvent", () => {
  const { input } = setup();
  fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: "23" } });
  expect(input.value).toBe("23");
});

test("Try userEvent", () => {
  const { input } = setup();
  userEvent.type(input, "23");
  expect(input.value).toBe("23");
});
```

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-formik/#:~:text=await%20user.type(screen.getByLabelText(/first%20name/i)%2C%20%27John%27)%0A%20%20await%20user.type(screen.getByLabelText(/last%20name/i)%2C%20%27Dee%27)) in the react testing library docs? It looks it's returning promise, so probably you'll have to `await` for it to be resolved

Comment: Yeah that was exactly the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It was simply that I needed to add async and await:

```
test("Try userEvent", async () => {
  const { input } = setup();
  await userEvent.type(input, "23");
  expect(input.value).toBe("23");
});
```

The `@testing-library/user-event` at `v13` didn't return a promise, but the update to `v14` does. At the moment, `create-react-app` provides `v13`, so it doesn't match the latest documentation. Quite confusing for the uninitiated!